# How to replace substrings in column of type String?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert the following Scala line (which extracts the digits from a string and which I used in the Scala shell):

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("only digits", regexp_replace(col("original"), "[^\\d]", ""))
```

to its Java equivalent and I am having problems with the conversion from `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` returned by `col("original")` to the String type required by `String.replaceAll()`.

I tried the following, but it doesn't compile (`cast` still returns a `Column`).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
Dataset<Row> df2 = df.withColumn("new", col("original").cast("string").replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
```

I also looked at the Column [javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) and in the static functions imported above but haven't seen anything to help. Thanks.

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am having problems with the conversion from `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` returned by `col("original")` to the `String` type required by `String.replaceAll()`.

It **won't** work.

You have to work with `Column` type since it represents a function that generates values for every row in that column. That's as much about the Spark type system as Java's (or Scala's to be precise).

The one and only solution is to use [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) object (or write a user-defined function aka UDF).

Use [regexp_replace](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_replace-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [translate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#translate-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) for your use case.

> **regexp_replace(Column e, String pattern, String replacement)** Replace all substrings of the specified string value that match regexp with rep.
>
> **translate(Column src, String matchingString, String replaceString)** Translate any character in the src by a character in replaceString.

Comment: Thanks, Jacek! So it turns out the Java code is identical with the Scala code, after all.

Comment: Yes! That was an easy answer (and could not have believed that you're asking about it) :)

Answer (score 2):

I have no words to say, @Jacek Laskowski was very explanatory and focus exactly at the point of your question. Nevertheless for the sake of a completeness i will provide an example of how this done with java, to be more  understandable.

```
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());


        List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create(1, "Hi I heard about *Spark"),
                RowFactory.create(2, "I wish *Java could use case classes"),
                RowFactory.create(3, "Logistic regression models are neat")
        );
        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty())
        });
        Dataset<Row> sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        Dataset<Row> transformedDS=sentenceData.withColumn("Replaced_Sentence", 
                functions.regexp_replace(sentenceData.col("sentence"),"\\*",""));
        transformedDS.show(false);
```

Output is:

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|label|sentence                           |Replaced_Sentence                  |
+-----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|1    |Hi I heard about *Spark            |Hi I heard about Spark             |
|2    |I wish *Java could use case classes|I wish Java could use case classes |
|3    |Logistic regression models are neat|Logistic regression models are neat|
+-----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```